# Rankings in Azure Table

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage

I am just stuck in a design problem. I want to assign ranks to user records in a table. They do some action on the site and given a rank on basis of leader board. And the select I want on them could be on Top 10, User's position, Top 10 logged in today etc.

I just can not find a way to store it in Azure table. Than I thought about storing custom collection object (a sorted list) in blob.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table entities are sorted by PartitionKey, RowKey.  While you could continually delete and recreate users (thus allowing you to change the PK, RK) to give the correct order, it seems like a bad idea or at least overkill.  Instead, I would probably store the data that you use the compute the rankings and periodically compute and store the rankings (as you say).  We do this a lot in our work - pre-compute what the data should look like in JSON view, store it in a blob, and let the UI query it directly.  The trick is to decide when to re-compute the view.  After a user does an item that would cause the rankings to be re-computed, I would probably queue a message and let a worker process go and re-compute the view.  This prevents too many workers from trying to update the data at once.